# Sum of a Series with imaginary numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to find the sum of a series but I get stuck.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+i}{4}\right)^n$$

where $i$ is the imaginary number.

I cannot really think of much else to do besides separate out the series into $(1/4)^n$ and $(1+i)^n$.

Comment: This is a geometric series. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the geometric series is

$$S={1\over 1-{1\over {1+i\over 4}}}$$

After simplification we get

$$S={1+i\over -3+i}={-1-2i\over 5}$$